# Magento 2 : Modify loaded product collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection

Can we modify loaded product collection in list.phtml file ? And if it is achievable then how can we modify it ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by modify?

Comment: @PhilippSander Modify means adding multiple attribute to sort collection